# Access Dcount function with 4 criteria

Tags: function, ms-access, dcount

I appreciate some help

I am trying to use Dcount function with 4 criteria

I have a text box in a form to count records on table_orders
The DCount function has 4 criteria:

The ID field in table_orders has to match the Form ID field

The field nature on table_orders has to be null

The field team on table_ordres has to be different than “Canceled”

The field ram (yes/no field) in table_ordes has to be “No”

I´ve been trying in many different ways with no success
This is my last try:

=DCount("*","Table_orders","ID=" & [ID]& " AND IsNull(nature)=true" & " AND   [team] <> "Canceled" &  AND [ram] ="No")

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
=DCount("*","Table_orders","ID = " & [ID] & " AND [nature] Is Null AND [team] <> 'Canceled' AND [ram] = 'No'")
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The function may be correct, but I think I have another problem: my form's data source is not Table_orders. I really have to work on this.